# Hadoop , hive , zookeeper etc

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I started to learn about hadoop . i was able to get some understanding about it but when i read about Hive , Pig and other tools of Apache , I get confused . So can someone just give a overview about hadoop and tools of Apache (Hive , Pig , Zookeeper etc) and i want to know how and where they are used in handling big data.

Comment: to much to explain in one thread can refer you http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fce.sysu.edu.cn%2Fhope%2FUploadFiles%2FEducation%2F2011%2F10%2F201110221516245419.pdf&ei=nAJ7U5GpNcOwOZqYgLgI&usg=AFQjCNGEY9qlKVlOCw6yz6__0WqvnCcG5g&bvm=bv.67229260,d.ZWU

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev that's a great book! I can't wait for the 3rd edition to come out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Apache Hadoop or Hadoop** is an open-source framework for storing and processing large-scale data sets on clusters of basic machines. Hadoop is a leading Apache projects being built and used by the free software community.

The Hadoop framework consists of the following modules:

- **Hadoop Common** - contains libraries and other services necessary for Hadoop modules.
- **HDFS or Hadoop Distributed File System** - a distributed file system that stores data on less powerful machines , providing high bandwidth over all clusters. HDFS is a filesystem That can store very large data sets by scaling out across a cluster of hosts . It has specific design and performance characteristics; In Particular , it is optimized for throughput instead of latency , and it achiever high availability through replication instead of redundancy .
- **Hadoop YARN** - a platform of responsible resource management calculations on clusters and then use them for user applications .
- **Hadoop MapReduce** - a programming model for processing large-scale data . MapReduce is a data processing paradigm that takes a specification of how the data will be input and output from its two stages (called map and reduce) and then applies this across arbitrarily large data sets. MapReduce integrates tightly with HDFS, ensuring that wherever possible, MapReduce tasks run directly on the HDFS nodes that hold the required data.

That was mainly how the Hadoop framework is presented. But beyond what I have quoted above, the Hadoop platform is now composed of a number of related projects as well - Pig, Hive, HBase, Spark, Mahout.

**Apache Hive** is a data warehouse infrastructure built on top of Hadoop for providing data summarization, query, and analysis.

**Apache Pig** is a high-level platform for creating MapReduce programs used with Hadoop with a language called *Pig Latin*

**Apache ZooKeeper** is a software project of the Apache Software Foundation, providing an open source distributed configuration service, synchronization service, and naming registry for large distributed systems.

**Apache Mahout** is a framework for scalable machine learning algorithms focused primarily in the areas of collaborative filtering, clustering and classification. It uses the Hadoop platform (but not necessary).

The list is long...

Comment: I am  a dot-net developer , will i be able to use my dot-net skills in any part of hadoop or i should jump to 
JAVA ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no knowledge about .Net at all. I can't answer that. But I believe that Microsoft should have solutions for that. Please check [this site](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/)